# total ordering in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I am trying to get Alloy to instantiate a set of nodes that are totally ordered, but don't seem to be able to do what I want. here is a simple case:

```
open util/ordering[S]

sig S {
   rel : set S
} 

pred show {}

run show for 4
```

I was expecting to see upto 4 nodes that are in a  chain but instead I see 4 nodes that are unrelated to each other. Jackson book section 6.1.1 suggests the use of util/ordering to define such things, but I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

The library module provides an ordering relation on S that can be accessed via functions such as next and prev (just open the code in the utils folder to see). That ordering relation can also be accessed explicitly if you prefer (but it's better to use the functions).

The relation rel that you defined is unaffected, and not constrained by opening the library module. If you think about it, it wouldn't make sense for rel to be constrained, since it's not mentioned in the open statement that instantiates the ordering (so the analyzer would have to guess which relation is the ordering).

Comment: I understand your comment that the user defined relation is not constrained. So my question was not quite correct. I was wondering if there is a way to constrain a particular relation to be a total order?